# Laravel optimize Eloquent Query

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Does someone know how to speed up such a query? When loading <3000 items it takes like ages until I get a result.

```
$data = Data::select('updated_at', 'data')
            ->where('device', $request->id)
            ->where('type', $request->type)
            ->get();
```

Comment: make index `device` and `type` column

Comment: Have you done any benchmarking around the querying? Is receiving the data slow from your database? Is it searching? Is the database rather large and you're causing a full scan of the table? Is `data` a json blob and you're having to stream a lot of data from the db to the php process, and then the process to end client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just search the word `Paginate` and read laravel documentation. You don't `get` all data and show it, you paginate them.